# How to populate multiple dropdownList with a single ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery

The below code generates 5 drop-down-lists.

```
@{
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { <tr>
    <td> @Html.Editor("[" + i + "].QNo", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control ", @type = "text",
        @placeholder = " QNo", @required = "", @id = "txtQNo", @style = "width:60px;" } }) </td>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td> @Html.DropDownList("[" + i + "].Question", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Select Question",
        new { @class = "form-control ", @id = "Question", @style = "width:900px;" })</td>

    </tr>
    }
  }
```

I am trying to populate the above 5 drop-down menu with a bunch of values I receive through my below ajax call

```js
$("#ReflectionType").on("change", function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/Question/GetQuestions",
        data: { TypeId: $('#ReflectionType').val() },
        datatype: "json",
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {

                var markup = '';
                $("#Question").append('<option value="' + value.Question + '">' + value.Question + '</option>');
               
            });
           
        }
    });
```

The above snippet only updates one of the drop-down list(the first drop-down menu) where it should be updating all five drop-down list.

Comment: Why are you keeping same id "Question" to all 5 drop-downs?

Comment: id's must be unique in a page (by definition)....use class instead

Comment: @RahulRaut In this case, how do i have a unique ID when the drop-down lists are created in a for-loop?

Comment: `new { @class = "form-control ", @id = "Question"+i, @style = "width:900px;" }` This is how you can generate unique id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@{
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { <tr>
    <td> @Html.Editor("[" + i + "].QNo", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control ", @type = "text",
    @placeholder = " QNo", @required = "", @id = "txtQNo", @style = "width:60px;" } })</td>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td> @Html.DropDownList("[" + i + "].Question", new SelectList(string.Empty,"Value", "Text"), "Select Question",
    new { @class = "form-control ", @id = "Question"+i, @style = "width:900px;" })</td>

</tr>
   }
}
```

This will generate unique id as follows Question0, Question1, Question2, Question3, Question4

```
$("#ReflectionType").on("change", function (event) {
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "/Question/GetQuestions",
    data: { TypeId: $('#ReflectionType').val() },
    datatype: "json",
    traditional: true,
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {

            var markup = '';
            for(let j = 0; j < 5; j++){
                $("#Question"+j).append('<option value="' + value.Question + '">' + value.Question + '</option>');
           }
        });

    }
});
```

As I can see your loop is running through 5 iteration you can run it in the same way and append the data from ajax call. Or you can use starts with selector as follows

```
$('[id^=Question]').each(function(index,element){
 $(element).append('<option value="' + value.Question + '">' + value.Question + '</option>');
})
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem. Happy Coding!